# Can the `bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low` variable make bot difficulty harder than 'Expert' (bot_difficulty 3)?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If I've set the bots to be initially at 'Expert' difficulty (`bot_difficulty 3`), will the [`bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers#Bots) variable (used to determine when the bot needs to make its difficulty harder, based on the average scores of human players) allow the bots' difficulty to go higher than 'Expert'? Or is 'Expert' the maximum bot difficulty allowed by the game, and bot difficulty won't go higher than that?

Comment: Just curious why you'd want to go higher.  On the highest difficulty they basically have ESP, aimbots, and have seemingly mastered the art of pre-firing.  On topic though I'm not sure.

Comment: @Mkalafut It's not that I would like to go higher. It's so that I can adjust bot_autodifficulty_threshold_low's value accordingly, depending on its effects.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense.  This may be a good question to ask over at the Steam community forums?  I'm sure if you post this in the Counter-Strike area you'll get some solid advice.

Answer (score 1):

I've tired this before, and found that the answer is no. Because there is no higher difficulty level programmed into the game, the bots are stuck at 3.

There are however servers I've heard of that offer bots with greater skill levels, they might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Elite is the highest bot rank and can only be accessed by going into your cs files, however autodifficulty works to an extent. There is also a command known as Bot_custom_strat

no one knows what it does nor if its for the future